# Excel master page concept

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel file that has several tabs.  Each of these tabs share a common header and formatting.  In other words, I want all tabs to look the same.  After creating a bunch of these tabs, I realize I need the header and formatting to change slightly.  However, now I must visit each worksheet and adjust it manually.

Is there some sort of templating function in Excel that will adjust all worksheets each time the underlying template changes (sort of a "master page" concept like Powerpoint)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change multiple tabs in one go.

Select the first tab, press and hold ctrl, then select all the tabs you want to make changes to.

then make the changes on the last tab you select.

Any changes you make will affect all the tabs selected.

Then click a single tab to unselect the group of tabs you have selected.

For more info see:

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/group-worksheets-4e1f7747-3d63-4fd7-8a36-838b05adc0f0

&

https://excelribbon.tips.net/T010653_Editing_the_Same_Cell_in_Multiple_Sheets.html